# JSON web token generator for JMeter

Tags: java, json, jmeter, jwt, beanshell

I'm trying to compare JWT value returned by an API call to an expected valid value in JMeter. For this, I need to generate the expected value in a pre-processor (either the BSF pre-processor or the Bean shell pre-processor) and then compare it to the extracted from the call response value.
Has anyone created anything similar before?
I currently use http://jwt.io/ to manually generate the expected values, but would like to dynamically generate these values in JMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is at the moment no out-of-box solution for processing JWT-signed requests in JMeter.

Looks like you have at least the following options:

1. Try to use [gatling](http://gatling.io/) instead of JMeter. Gatling has already implemented extension for this payload - [gatling-jwt](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/gatling-jwt) - but seems that it supports currently only GET requests.
2. Possibly you can try to extend standard HTTP Request Sampler or custom [REST Sampler](https://github.com/ATLANTBH/jmeter-components) with JWT signing using any [java implementation of JWT](http://jwt.io/#libraries-io) - like it's done in [OAuth Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/OAuthSampler/) plugin for OAuth payload.
   But it may appear quite complex way which requires a bit of development experience as well as will be not error-prone - inaccurate implementation may cause performance degradation and affect your test-results.
3. Approach with Pre- and Post-processors for JWT-signing and response verification you've mentioned in your question seems to be reasonable compromise.
   When I've stuck on the same issue my first and quite successful approach with Pre- and PostProcessors usage too.
   Several points to note:

   - use JSR233 (both [PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)) + Groovy instead of Beanshell for performance reasons (for details you can look into [this article](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance));
   - select any stable java implementation of JWT from [list of available](http://jwt.io/#libraries-io);
     I've used [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) and find it good enough as well simple to use;
   - perform request body JWT-signing in PreProcessor, store signed body into variable, send it along with HTTP request as Body Data and decode response in PostProcessor;

     ```
     HTTP Request // your http call
     Body Data = ${jwtSignedBody} // variable with request body already signed in pre-processor
         JSR233 PreProcessor // sign here your body data and put into variable
         JSR233 PostProcessor // decode JWT-signed response
     ```

     - [request JWT signing](https://gist.github.com/aliesbelik/f1d47a7419e5c88efe5b)
     - [response decoding](https://gist.github.com/aliesbelik/10095effb071935c158c)
   - it may be extremely useful for debugging and further processing to update in PostProcessor response body with decoded response like in the script above.

Comment: I'm trying the 3rd approach and I get the "unable to resolve class com.google.gson.JsonObject" error. Would you know how to resolve this class?

Comment: So I managed to obtain the gson jar file. Now I'm getting the following exception:

javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setSuccessful() on null object
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
 at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
 ...

Comment: Well... the actual exception is javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jwts for class: Script8

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BeanShell PreProcessor to calculate the JWT bearer token prior to the HTTP Request sampler.

Here is the script that can generate a JWT bearer token for use in HTTP requests:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

String jwtIssuer = "your-issuer-here";
String signingKey = "your-signing-key-here";
String subject = "your-subject-here";
// Additional parts of payload here if you like
String groups = "[]";

//The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder()
      .setPayload("{\n" +
              "  \"iss\": \"" + jwtIssuer + "\",\n" +
              "  \"iat\": " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime() / 1000 + ",\n" +
              "  \"sub\": \"" + username + "\",\n" +
              "  \"groups\": " + groups + "\n" +
              "}")
      .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT")
      .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey.getBytes());


vars.put("bearerToken", builder.compact());
```

Obviously hard coding the `subject` is not too valuable, because otherwise you could just hard code the bearer token in the http request. So you can use `vars.get` to get jmeter variables. In my case I load the subject from a "CSV Data Set config" and then set `String subject = vars.get("subject");`

Now you can create an HTTP Header Manager on your HTTP Request sampler to add the bearer token:

```
          <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Authorization</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">Bearer ${bearerToken}</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </HeaderManager>
```

Run your test and you should see your bearer token is present, and your request is authenticated.

[image: JWT bearer token present in request]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't have direct JWT processing capabilities. But we can write a custom JMeter extension for this purpose.
We can use generic JWT token processing libraries for our implementation.

I did one such implementation for my testing requirements. You can access that code on Github and get an idea as well.
https://github.com/gvasanka/jwt-builder-jmeter-ext